# Rendering views inside layouts

Tags: forms, widget, yii2, render

I'm trying to use a form in my main.php layout. The form is in the view folder with views related to my newsletter model and controller.

So far I've tried to create the following widget:**

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use app\models\Newsletter;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;


class NewsletterForm extends Widget

{
    public function run()
{ 
    $model = new Newsletter;

    return $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
}

?>
```

The widget is located in: app\components\NewsletterForm.php

I have a DB model called Newsletter.php and a database table called newsletter.

There is a folder inside app\views called newsletter. This folder as the _form.php where i want the user to input name and email to receive the newsletter.

The problem is I need to load the _form in views\newsletter in the footer of main.php

When I use the widget I always get the error:

```
The view file does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/beladona/components/views/_form.php
```

How can I render the form inside views\newsletter\ _form.php.
The form needs to render inside the footer of main.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extensive discussion with the OP, we decided that a widget wasn't appropriate for his use case. Widgets are intended to be independent pieces of code, capable of being re-used in different situations. All he wanted to do was render a view file from an existing MVC combination

So here is what we settled on;

Layout being used is main.php We edited this for the following;

```
use app\models\Newsletter;

echo $this->render('@app/views/site/_index', 'model' => new Newsletter);
```

This has the advantage of keeping the existing form he is using.

He then needed to specify a controller/action combination to use in the form, like this;

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 
'action' => Url::to(['newsletter/create']) 
]);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97784/discussion-between-joe-miller-and-andre-castro).